# Is there a ticket to see just Brunelleschi's Cupola and if so, can I buy it online?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, museums, florence

I'd like to visit *Cupola del Brunelleschi* in Florence but noticed that you can only buy online a 15€ ticket for the whole *Museo dell'Opera del Duomo*. Since I won't stay in Florence for long:

Is there a ticket to see just the Cupola and if so, can I buy it online?

Answer (score 6):

**To date there's no way to purchase individual admission tickets for the *Museo del Duomo* monuments in Florence.** The only ticket you can buy is the combined admission to all monuments in the complex. This has been the case since at least two years. Quoting from the [official Florence blog](http://operaduomo.firenze.it/blog/posts/3-cose-che-dovete-sapere-sul-biglietto-unico):

> Da oltre due anni la Cattedrale di Santa Maria del Fiore, la Cupola di Brunelleschi, il Campanile di Giotto, il Battistero, l'antica basilica di Santa Reparata e il Museo dell'Opera sono visitabili acquistando un unico biglietto del costo di 15 euro.

[Tickets can be bought online here.](http://en.grandemuseodelduomo.waf.it/museo_dett.php?idtour=8484)